# How do I ask for user input and based on that input ask for following input

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to write a code that asks if a person completed a physical activity and if the user enters yes then  want to ask what the activity was but if they answer no then the program just prints that they didn't complete an activity. Here's what I've got so far

```
while True:
    largemuscle=input('Did they complete a large muscle activity for 1 hour today? y or n:')
    if largemuscle not in ('y','n'):
        print('not and appropriate choice please enter y or n')
        continue
    else:
        break
if largemuscle=='y':
    activity=input('What activity did they do for large muscle?:')
    largemuscle='He completed his large muscle today. For large muscle he'

elif largemuscle=='n':

    largemuscle='He did not complete a large muscle activity today'

print(largemuscle,activity)
```

The problem I'm running into is if the user enters 'n', then there is a traceback stating that activiy is not defined. If I add activity under the elif then I would need to have it be blank. also I want this printed off with other inputs in a paragraph and dont want there to be whitespace if the user enters n for the activity.

Comment: You've already identified that you need to define `activity` as a blank string in the `elif` block. Alternatively, move the `print(...)` to inside the `if largemuscle == 'y'` block. Add another `print()` for only `largemuscle` in the `elif` block. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. The only thing you have to do is to initialize the `activity` variable and assign it to an empty string above your `while` loop:

```
activity=''
```